# How to segment a database for an application accessing it (a.k.a. single database for multiple users problem)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have built a web application for one user, but now I would like to offer it to many users (it's an application for photographer(s)).

## Multiple databases problems

I first did this by creating an application for each user, but this has many problems, like:

- Giving access to a new user can't be automated (or is very difficult) since I have to create a subdomain, a database, initial tables, copy code to a new location, etc. This is tedious to do by hand!
- I can't as easily create reports and statistics of usage, like how many projects do my users have, how many photos, etc.

## Single database problems

But having just one database for each users creates it's own problems in code:

- Now I have to change the DB schema to accommodate extra users, like the projects table having a user_id column (the same goes for some other tables like settings, etc.).
- I have to look at almost each line of code that accesses the database and edit the SQL for selecting and inserting, so that I sava data for that specific user, at the same time doing joins so that I check permissions (`select ... from projects inner join project_users ... where user_id = ?`).
- If I forget to do that at one spot in the code it means security breach or another unpleasant thing (consider showing user's projects by just doing `select * from projects` like I used to do - it will show all users' projects).
- *Backup*: backup is harder because there's more data for the whole database and if a user says: "hey, I made a mistake today, can you revert the DB to yesterday", I can't as easily do that.

## A solution?

I have read multiple questions on stackoverflow and have decided that I should go the "single database" route. But I'd like to get rid of the problems, if it's possible.
So I was thinking if there was a way to segment my database somehow so that I don't get these nasty (sometimes invisible) bugs? 
I can reprogram the DB access layer if needed, but I'm using SQLs and not OO getter and setter methods.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a silver bullet on this one - though there are some things you can do.

Firstly, you could have your new design use a different MySQL user, and deny that user "select" rights on tables that should only be accessed through joins with the "users" table. You can then create a view which joins the two tables together, and use that whenever you run "select" queries. This way, if you forget a query, it will fail spectacularly, instead of silently. You can of course also limit insert, update and delete in this way - though that's a lot harder with a view.

**Edit**
So, if your application currently connects as "web_user", you could revoke select access on the projects table from that user. Instead, you'd create a view "projects_for_users", and grant "select" permissions on that view to a new user - "photographer", perhaps. The new user should also not have select access to "projects".

You could then re-write the application's data access step by step, and you'd be sure that you'd caught every instance where your app selects projects, because it would explode when trying to retrieve data - neither of your users would have "select" permissions on the projects table.

As a little side bonus - the select permission is also required for updates with a where clause, so you'd also be able to find instances where the application updates the project table without having been rewritten.

Secondly, you want to think about the provisioning process - how will you grant access to the system to new users? Who does this? Again, by separating the database user who can insert records into "users", you can avoid stupid bugs where page in your system does more than you think it does. With this kind of system, there are usually several steps that make up the provisioning process. Make sure you separate out the privileges for those tasks from the regular user privileges.

**Edit**
Provisioning is the word for setting up a service for a new user (I think it comes from the telephony world, where phone companies will talk about provisioning a new service on an existing phone line). It usually includes a whole bunch of business processes - and each step in the process must succeed for the next one to start. So, in your app, you may need to  set up a new user account, validate their email address, set up storage space etc. Each of those steps needs to be considered as a step in the process, not just a single task.

Finally, while you're doing this, you may as well think about different levels of privilege. Will your system merit different types of user? Photographers, who can upload work, reviewers who can't? If that's a possible feature extension, you may want to build support for that now, even if the only type of user you support on go-live is photographer.

Comment: Great tip about accessing data through views! Never thought of this but it's a great suggestion. But could you maybe elaborate on this _provisioning process_?

Comment: Also, could you expand on this views approach? How would you do it? Would you create one user for the application and another one for administrative access and application?

Answer (score 0):

Well, time to face some hard facts -- I think. The "single database problem" that you describe, is not a problem, but a normal (usual) design. Quite often, **one** is simply a special case of **many**.

For some reason you have designed a web-app for one user -- not many of those around.

So, time to re-design.

Comment: Well yes, I _am_ doing a redesign and was wondering if there was a way to segment the DB so that I wouldn't have to think about additional SQL joins and where clauses and worrying that I have made (will make) a mistake somewhere that would be a "security breach".